# Select a column filter value in pivot table in Excel sheet from C# using Excel.interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop, console-application

I have a excel file  which contains nearly 15 sheets. Each sheet contains one pivot table which is created by another user. All pivot tables takes data from one sheet called "data". 
My C# console application program updates the data in "data" sheet in particular time interval.

My requirement is I have to select the current and previous month value in pivot table column label filter in each sheet after updated the data sheet using C# excel interop.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it like this

```
            Excel._Application XL = new Excel.Application();
            Excel._Workbook WB;
            Excel._Worksheet SH;
            WB = XL.Workbooks.Open(@filepath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            SH = (Excel.Worksheet)WB.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                lastUsedRow = SH.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing).Row;

                for (int i = 1; i < lastUsedRow; i++)
                {
                    if (GetCell(SH, i, 2) == "")
                    {
                          //Do your code
                    }
                }

        public static string GetCell(Excel._Worksheet worksheet, int row, int column)
        {
            Excel.Range range = worksheet.Cells[row, column] as Excel.Range;
            if (range == null || range.Value2 == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return range.Value2.ToString();
        }

        private static void ReleaseComObject(object activeXObject)
        {
            if (activeXObject != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(activeXObject);
                activeXObject = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. But where you are using pivot table? How it will select values in pivot table column filter value?

Comment: I am just selecting value from excel file

Comment: But I need to select column filter values in pivot table in each sheet.

Comment: How is this relevant to the question at all?

Comment: Or maybe this is a kind of "like question, like answer".